# Unit of integrated vapor transport (IVT)

Tags: cdo-climate, era5, cds.copernicus

I am trying to calculate IVT from ERA5 data. But my values are not matching with other published papers. The values in the paper are in the range of 100-1000 but i am getting the values which are less than 1. I think i am making mistakes in the unit. Please see the following equation and units.

As per several papers the equation of IVT is as follows:
[image]
where q is the specific humidity (kg kg−1); u and v are the zonal and meridional componentsof wind (m s−1); g is the acceleration due to gravity (m s−2).
The unit of IVT is given as kg m-1 s-1. I don't understand how we are getting this unit?

Comment: it would help if you posted your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating over pressure which has units of kg m-1 s-2

So that gives [m-1 s2] [m s-1] [kg m-1 s-2] =  kg m-1 s-1

However I've flagged to close as this is not a question about programming, should be posted to an alternative SO site.